# Does the mail app in iPhones still use POP for Gmail? Or is it updated to use IMAP?

Tags: iphone, email

Does the mail app in iPhones still use POP for Gmail? Or is it updated to use IMAP?

Answer (score 6):

If you pick the Gmail option when setting up your account, it will use IMAP. However, if you set it up [as descibed here](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740), it uses ActiveSync. Doing it this way gives you push notification as well as contact and calendar sync.

Comment: Holy crap that is awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with Google Apps accounts for a hosted domain. At least, I haven't been able to find a set of settings that will work for my email account. It verifies the account information successfully but when I go into Mail it says it can't connect.

Comment: @DougC, this works for Google Apps with hosted domains too. I'm using that with great success. Open a new question here, add all possible details, and let's see if we can get you aboard ActiveSync!

Answer (score 1):

The "Gmail" option for iPhone mail configuration has always used IMAP. I would, however, recommend configuring it as an Exchange account, especially now that iOS officially supports multiple Exchange accounts (previously the domain of jailbreakers only). Doing so will push emails, contacts, and calendars directly to the phone, though you won't be able to sync Notes like you can when using the "Gmail" option.